# How to use .contains() or any other function to see if any part of a string is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, contains

I am trying to cut down and make my code simpler since my original method is not very readable and I get a lot of hard to understand errors for which I have to scan all of the code word by word as it is all one long line.

Lets say the text input was for

In my original code, I wrote :

```
//Example : You want to know if any of your favorite games were licensed by Nintendo

var tsf = (The value of a textInput in string form)

tsf.toLowerCase()

//Lets say the textinput said "Name your favorite games"

if(tsf.contains('mario') || tsf.contains('pokemon') || tsf.contains('mortal kombat')||etc,etc) {

    Alert.alert('At least one of these games was licensed by Nintendo')

}
```

This works but in the real code there are a lot more "games" and it requires each and every item in the list as it is related to a health project I'm working on.

My 2nd idea was to create an array with all the elements and see if the array contains tsf

```
nintendoGames = ['mario','pokemon','mortal kombat','zelda','tetris',etc]

if(nintendoGames.contains(tsf)){
    Alert.alert('This game was licensed by Nintendo')
}
```

This also works but only if tsf is a single word. Incase

```
tsf = 'mario, zelda'
```

the array method would not work since the array only contains 'mario' and 'zelda' and not the string 'mario, zelda'

I want to be able to scan to see if *any* part of the string contains *any* one of the elements in the array and so far, only the first solution works for me. If there is a modification in the .contains() function that works or if there is a certain script I have to write, it would be very useful. I wasn't able to find much online about this.

I am working on React.js with expo to host the app.

Answer (score 2):

First, we convert the string to an array using 'split'.
Since we separate the games in the string with ', ' your code should be like:

```
tsf.split(', '); // we receive: ['mario','zelda'].
```

Then we use 'some' method to check if some of the elements in the array we created are in the 'nintedoGames' array.

```js
const tsf = 'mario, zelda';

const nintendoGames = ['mario', 'pokemon', 'mortal kombat', 'zelda', 'tetris'];

const result = tsf.split(', ').some(game => nintendoGames.includes(game.toLowerCase()));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, code-only answers are no good. Please explain what your code does and what the OP did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
let nintendoGames = ['mario','pokemon','mortal kombat','zelda','tetris'];

let str = "This is a mario games where you can play the way you like.";

if(nintendoGames.some(n => str.toLowerCase().includes(n.toLowerCase())))
   alert("This game was licensed by Nintendo");
```